# Proof that $|S| \leq |T|$ if $S \subseteq T$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Let $S$ and $T$ be sets. I am having trouble proving that if  $S \subseteq T$, then $|S| \leq |T|$, where $|S|$ is the cardinality of $S$.

Comment: What is your definition of $|S|\leq |T|$?  Something to do with an injective map perhaps?  What about the identity map?

Comment: Sorry I should have included this in the problem. $S$, $T$, are sets and $|S|$ denotes the cardinatlity of the set $S$

Answer (score 3):

Given sets $S$ and $T$, $|S| \le |T|$ if and only if there is an injective function $S \to T$. If $S \subseteq T$, can you think of a natural injective function $S \to T$?

Comment: Would a function $f: S \rightarrow T$ where $f(x) = x$ work, since the function is bijective across its entire domain?

Comment: @lithium123 you don't refer to a function being "bijective across its domain" especially if the function is not itself bijective.  It is however *injective* which is exactly all that is desired.

Comment: @lithium123: That is an injective function (as required), but it's not bijective.

Comment: @lithium123: Your function is _not bijective_ if $S\ne T$. Fortunately, however it _is_ injective, which is all you need.

Comment: Well that was a fast and consistent chain of replies :P